# DC.js Crossfilter on "nested" dimensions

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm quite confused and might need help just formulating the question, so please give good comments...

I'm trying to crossfilter some data where each data point has its own sub-dataset that I want to chart and filter on as well. Each point represents a geographic region, and associated with each point is a time series which measures a certain metric over time.

Here's what I've got so far: http://michaeldougherty.info/dcjs/

The top bar chart shows a particular value for 10 regions, and the choropleth is linked with the same data. Now, below that are two composite line charts. Each line corresponds to a region -- there are 10 lines in each graph, and each graph is measuring a different metric over time. I would like the lines to be filtered as well, so if one bar is selected, only one line will show on the line chart.

Moreover, I want to be able to filter by time on the line charts (through brushing) in addition to some other filter, so I can make queries like "filter out all regions whose line value between 9 AM and 5 PM is less than 20,000", which would also update the bar and choropleth charts.

This is where I'm lost. I'm considering scrapping DC.js for this and using `crossfilter` and d3.js directly because it seems so complicated, but I would love it if I'm missing something and DC.js can actually handle this. I'd also love some ideas on where to start implementing this in straight `crossfilter`, because I haven't fully wrapped my head around that yet either.

How does one deal with datasets within datasets?

Screenshot of the link above included for convenience:

[image]

Comment: I'd start by un-nesting your data. Can you explain what sort of dimensions the un-nested data would have? Sounds like you would have an additional time dimension and an additional 'metric' dimension?

Comment: I am wondering if/how one can crossfilter nested data... I am afraid that you can only crossfilter the raw records by adding dimensions, and then nest the resulting subset. But I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: @EthanJewett, if I flattened the data, then each datum would have an ID, a few other values, and then about 100 more variables, one for each time of day in the time-series. Since I want to filter on time ranges, I'm not sure how I can filter on a range of dimensions. Does that make sense? These ideas are helping me, feel free to shoot out more.

Comment: @maackle I'd make time-of-day a column as well. I realize this could result in your data set getting quite large, but in my experience, to work with Crossfilter, data should be pretty flat.

Comment: @EthanJewett, that's an answer!  Why you always just comment?

Comment: @Gordon I don't *always* just comment ;-) If I feel like I can definitively answer, then I post an answer. If I need more information or I just have a one-line suggestion, then I comment. :-)

Comment: For the record, @EthanJewett's "answer" did indeed lead me in the right direction. I flattened my data, which became highly redundant but it was what was needed to work with crossfilter. Thanks!